# i have to open set association of a program from control panel using vb script or powershell

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, vbscript

I have used the below script just to see what are the defaults set for internet explorer.

```vbs
Option Explicit
Dim oShell, sWinDir
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sWinDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WINDIR%")
oShell.Run sWinDir & "\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=internet%20explorer"
Set oShell = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

This works fine for Internet Explorer but when I tried for Firefox or Outlook it doesn't show anything. Even though the window opens, it reflects nothing as if in case the name doesn't exist. Please suggest

```vbs
Option Explicit
Dim oShell, sWinDir
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sWinDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WINDIR%")
oShell.Run sWinDir & "\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=firefox"
Set oShell = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

In powershell I am using the below script this also works fine for google chrome and internet explorer but when I have to open other programs like work firefox excel then it wont work.

[image: screenshot]

```
function Set-IEAsDefaultBrowser {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
    Start-Process $env:windir\system32\control.exe -ArgumentList '/name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=Outlook'
    Sleep 2
}
Set-IEAsDefaultBrowser
```

The image attached show how it looks like when I tried for outlook or word.

Answer (score 1):

i have resolved it myself.

Actually i have to write the registered application name, earlier i am using names like word but it has to be Word.Application.16.

Find the registered application name from the key below.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications

Answer (score 0):

If i use it like this,

```
Set ob = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sWinDir = ob.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WINDIR%")
ob.Run sWinDir & "\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=firefox"
```

Associate a file type or protocol with a program for Firefox opens.